# Resolving a DevExpress.Xpo.Exceptions.SessionMixingException

Tags: exception, dependency-injection, devexpress, xpo

I'm adding an object to another object like so:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
AnotherClass.bar.add(foo);  // bar is getting assigned with dependency injection in AnotherClass
```

This causes a DevExpress.Xpo.Exceptions.SessionMixingException as follows:

> Initialization method
>   Test.SetUp threw
>   exception. DevExpress.Xpo.Exceptions.SessionMixingException:
>   DevExpress.Xpo.Exceptions.SessionMixingException: The
>   'Foo' object belongs to a different session.

How does one grab get a hold of the session from AnotherClass to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply load the foo object within AnotherClass' Session with,

```
foo = AnotherClass.Session.GetObjectByKey<Foo>(foo.Oid);
AnotherClass.bar.add(foo);
```

You can read more how the session works at http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/articles/SessionManagementCaching.xml